# Tuple conversion in python to list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a tuple like

```
a = (1,2,3,4).
```

Is it possible to change the tuple to

```
a = [('roll', 1),('roll',2),('roll', 3),('roll', 4)]
```

Comment: One does not simply "change the tuple." You can change the value of the name `a` to be the appropriate tuple, but tuples are immutable and cannot themselves be changed. In other words, you change `a`, not the tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple list comprehension here -

```
a = [("roll", i) for i in a]
```

OP

```
[('roll', 1), ('roll', 2), ('roll', 3), ('roll', 4)]
```

More about list comprehension [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** - simply do a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/):

```
a = [('roll', i) for i in a]
```

Note that doing this will *rebind* `a`! (See the note by @ShadowRanger.)

Comment: Technically, it *rebinds* `a`; if `a` is aliased elsewhere under a different name, that alias is unchanged (e.g. `b = a; a = [('roll', i) for i in a]` will preserve the original value of `a`, accessible through the `b` alias). Subtle distinction, but important in some cases. Since `a` is initially bound to a `tuple`, it's not possible to mutate the `tuple` itself.

Comment: Thanks, @ShadowRanger! That's very informative - I've edited my answer to reflect that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Easily. With [a list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions):

```
a = [("roll", x) for x in a]
```

or [with `itertools` stuff](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
import itertools

a = list(zip(itertools.repeat('roll'), a))  # No need to wrap in list if you'll iterate the result and discard it
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `map` function:

```
i = (1,2,3,4)
list(map(lambda x: ('roll',x), i))
```

Comment: Note: Any use of `map` that requires a `lambda` to work is more efficiently and more clearly expressed as a list comprehension or generator expression, since the listcomp/genexpr can inline the work done in the `lambda`, avoiding (relatively expensive) function call overhead for trivial work.

Answer (score 0):

Or another alternative using list()

```
 list(zip(["roll"]*4, a))
```